# ActionController::UnknownFormat when using format.turbo_stream in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, stimulusjs, ruby-on-rails-7, hotwire-rails

Hey I'm new to turbo_streams and am stuck on why I'm getting this error.

Properties partial:

```
<div id="properties"
     data-action="map-marker-clicked@window->@mapmarker#mapMarkerClicked"
     data-controller="mapmarker"
     data-mapmarker-target="properties_list">
  <%= "#{@properties.length} properties" %>

  <%= turbo_stream_from "properties" %>
  <%= turbo_frame_tag "properties" do %>
    <% @properties.each do |property| %>
      <%= render property %>
      <p>
        <%= link_to "View this property", property %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And my controller:

```
  def index
    @properties = location_search? ? Property::SearchByLocation.call(search_params[:value]) : Property.all

    @markers = Property::GenerateGoogleApiMapMarkers.call(property_or_properties: @properties)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.turbo_stream do
        render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.replace(@properties, partial: 'properties/properties')
      end
    end
  end
```

Bit more context: I plan to trigger this reload from a stimulus controller (when the user clicks a marker on the google maps I want to refresh the properties section with the coordinates of the marker as the way to organise the properties (the closest to the marker would show at the top).

I get the ActionController::UnknownFormat error when I go to http://localhost:3000/properties

[image]

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the exact same problem and have not solved it.

Comment: Hi @DavidLazar by any chancve have you found a solution ?

Comment: @Maxence, any luck with a solution?

Comment: @bcarp121177 my bad. I had wrongly stubbed the user. Then Devise was redirecting me to GET Sign-in forwarding .turbo_sream format. Which failed.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose the request that triggered the error was an HTML request (without the `Accept: text/vnd.turbo-stream.html` HTTP header).

You can verify this by checking your application logs. For each request, you'll find a line indicating which format is use to process it. In your case it should be something like:

```
Processing by PropertiesController#index as HTML
```

In your controller, the `respond_to` block only contains `format.turbo_stream` as accepted MIME type :

```rb
respond_to do |format|
  format.turbo_stream do
    render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.replace(@properties, partial: 'properties/properties')
  end
end
```

As a result, your action is unable to render HTML, resulting in an `ActionController::UnknownFormat` error.

In order to fix this issue you should enable HTML responses as so:

```rb
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { ... }
  format.turbo_stream do
    render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.replace(@properties, partial: 'properties/properties')
  end
end
```

Comment: do you mean within the `respond_to do` block?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue and solved it by manually registering the mime type by adding the below line to config/initializers/mime_type.rb.

```
Mime::Type.register "text/vnd.turbo-stream.html", :turbo_sream
```

See https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/pull/93 for some background.

Comment: `Mime::Type.register "text/vnd.turbo-stream.html", :turbo_stream` fixed command

Answer (score 0):

Try to explicitly pass `method: :get` in your `link_to` or `button_to` method

I think it`s somehow bond with TurboDrive and how it hijack requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can add :

> format: 'turbo_stream'

for the Turbo Stream Link.

Some examples :

```
 - url_opts = {format: 'turbo_stream', frame: 'submission_form', partial: 'bulk_upload'}

 = form_tag import_path(url_opts) do
```

or when you want to generate a link in JS :

```
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append("format", "turbo_stream");
return mainUrl + "?" + params.toString();
```